# How to run link which is in terminal of vs code?

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I am unable to run  http://127.0.0.1:5001/  this link via terminal
need help :(

- Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 604-307-579
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you are trying to do.

But, I am guessing you are creating a website via Flask and you don't know how to open the website.

The website is being hosted on port 5001.

So, you should open this url in your preferred web browser.

http://localhost:5001

> Note that http://127.0.0.1:5001/  is the same as http://localhost:5001